# Pubspec.yaml 1.22.1

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, yaml

So I am creating my application and decided to go to pubspec.yaml to see my fonts. And when I look at my pubspec.yaml, I only see this code. 1.22.1 . I don't know what happened. Last time I know, I re install my android studio because it got an error that I needed to fix and since the, this happened. What should I do? It doesn't have errors or bug my app works fine but how can I edit my pubspec if this happen

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Oh i already resolve it I just need to re install my android studio but thank you for your reply. God Bless